# changing Squid proxy from 3.5 to 5.6 and 1024 bit cert

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid

we use Squid ver 3.5 with SSL inspection in our company. Users have Squid's cert added as trusted root-CA in their browsers. It has worked for over 4 years. Now I want to upgrade Squid version into v5.6 . The problem is that my existing Squid  priv.key/cert are 1024 bit and it looks like Squid 5.6 doesn't support it. There is an error message when starting:  ERROR: Failed to acquire TLS certificate '/etc/squid/ssl_cert/squid.crt'

My question is if there's any possibility to force Squid 5 to use old key/cert OR regenerate  somehow existing keys to 2048 bit?  I want to avoid importing new CA cert in the user browsers...
I tried to generate a new priv.key + CSR and sign it with my old CA cert (this one which is trusted in user's browsers). It works - new Squid starts, but user browsers unfortunately don't see it as trusted.

thx for any hints

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's solved. I've generated intermediate certificate (signed by the old root CA) and I'm using this new (2048 bit) intermediate certificate in Squid.